# Selecting multiple values with Select by Attributes in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

Can anyone help me with selecting multiple values from the attribute table?

I tried `"Classes"='14'AND'07'` but it doesn't work.

Comment: A great and detailed source is http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000

Answer (score 21):

A more elegant solution is:

> "Classes" in ('14','15',....)

Comment: In case of null USE inverted commas OR NOT e.g for above code  "Classes" in (NULL,'14','15',....) OR "Classes" in ('NULL','14','15',....) N.B. Only single inverted comma care it..

Answer (score 13):

You would need to break up your selection statement into two separate parts:

"Classes" = '14' OR "Classes" = '07'

Edit: Changed from AND to OR, since as noted in the comments, AND cannot work in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion RyanL. The AND in the middle does not work. But the OR works.

Comment: The AND doesn't work because you cannot have both 14 and 07 in the same field for the same feature. If you have multiple cases you want to select, use the syntax: fieldname in ('value1','value2','value3') for strings or without '' for integers.

Comment: What happens if I have hundreds and hundreds of values that I want the database to search and select? In fact I have a whole CSV file worth of these values... I can't possible fit them all in the little query box using SQL... Is there a more robust solution?